# Нужно реализовать функцию подсчета суммы столбца в SQLite таблице используя QtSql

Tags: sql, sqlite, pyqt6

Нужно реализовать функцию подсчета суммы столбца в SQLite таблице используя QtSql.
Метод .exec() на сколько я понимаю возвращает bool.
Какой метод нужно использовать подскажите пожалуйста?

```
def total_balance(self):
    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.exec("""SELECT SUM(Balance) FROM expenses""")
    query.first()
    return query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Док](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtSql/QSqlQuery.html)

```
query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
//Выполняем запрос.
query.exec("SELECT SUM(Balance) FROM expenses") 

//  если есть результат, то получаем его и преобразуем в строку
if query.next():
    return query.value(0).toString()

return -1
```

Comment: можете рассказать как это работает?

Comment: @ДенисБудяк добавил ссылку на мануал. Можете почитать ещё вот тут.  https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-sqlstatements.html

Comment: у меня также выпадает ошибка когда пытаюсь вставить результат функции в Label self.ui.current_balance.setText(self.conn.total_balance)

Comment: @ДенисБудяк  какая ошибка?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dennis/PycharmProjects/Finances_app/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    window = ExpenseTracker()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dennis/PycharmProjects/Finances_app/main.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.ui.current_balance.setText(self.conn.total_balance)
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QLabel.setText' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QLabel.setText(method)
Supported signatures:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QLabel.setText(str)

Comment: я так понимаю он хочет получить на вход метода строковый тип. Только вот в вашем решении есть toString

Comment: @ДенисБудяк скобки не забыли у toString()?

Comment: есть скобки, всё как у вас

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142155/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and--).